# Google App Engine not stopping apps

Tags: google-app-engine

I downloaded eclipse (june 4.2) and started up an app engine project. Deploys fine, but it never seems to terminate properly. I make code changes and they don't show up in the browser with a refresh. When I hover my mouse over the run button it says "already running" in the tooltip. I have to completely restart eclipse to pick up the changes.

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks updating to SDK 1.7.2 fixes the problem.